# how to read subfolders and files contain in it

Tags: c#

i can read the folder files by using BETALIB reader, but its to big to read by giving the path one by in the folderbrowserdialog
i can read folder but in that folder there are many folders and files i want to read the subfolders  .

for eaxample :-
E:\EXE\ttd\ttd1\ttd2\bsem\f1.dat
E:\EXE\ttd\ttd1\ttd2\MCDEX\f1.dat

i want to read the files by giving the path in the folderbrowserdialog
EX:E:\EXE

if i select the path E:\EXE it should read all the subfolders and files contain in it.

can any one say me what i should change in the code

```
    private void btnSourceBOMCX_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fbdSourceBOMCX.Description = "Please select BOMCX source folder";
        fbdSourceBOMCX.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop;
        if ((fbdSourceBOMCX.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel) || (fbdSourceBOMCX.SelectedPath != ""))
        {
            sourceBOMCX = fbdSourceBOMCX.SelectedPath;
            if (File.Exists(sourceBOMCX + "\\Master"))
            {
                txtSourceBOMCX.Text = fbdSourceBOMCX.SelectedPath;
                Interaction.SaveSetting ((new Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase()).Info.Title  , "RealTime Converter", "sourceBOMCX", fbdSourceBOMCX.SelectedPath); 
            }
            else
            {

            }


        }
    }
```

private void bgManual_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {

```
        try
        {
            int DT = int.Parse(txtSelectedDate.Text);
            BETALIB.BLReader Reader = new BETALIB.BLReader();
            BETALIB.BLReader Reader1 = new BETALIB.BLReader();
            Reader.OpenDirectory(txtSourceBOBOMCX.Text);
            Reader.ReadMaster();
            string path = txtDestinationBOBOMCX.Text + "\\XYZ-" + txtSelectedDate.Text + ".txt";
            StreamWriter Strwriter = new StreamWriter(path);

            try
            {
                while (Reader.iMaRecordsLeft > 0)
                {
                    string SecName = Reader.sMaSecName;
                    string Symbol = Reader.sMaSecSymbol;
                    Symbol = prefix + Symbol;
                    int abc = 0;
                    int xyz = lbselectedBOBOMCX.Items.Count - 1;
                    while (abc <= xyz)
                    {
                        if (SecName == (string)lbselectedBOBOMCX.Items[abc])
                        {

                            Reader.OpenSecurityByName(Reader.sMaSecName);
                            Reader.SeekToEnd();
                            Reader.Seek(-1);
                            Reader.ReadDay();
                            float O = Reader.dSeOpen;
                            float H = Reader.dSeHigh;
                            float L = Reader.dSeLow;
                            float C = Reader.dSeClose;
                            double V = Reader.dSeVolume;
                            double OI = Reader.dSeOpenInterest;
                            string T = Reader.iSeTime.ToString();
                            string D = Reader.iSeDate.ToString();

                            label9.Text = SecName + "/";
                            if (int.Parse(D) == DT)
                            {
                                string a = string.Concat(SecName, ",", Symbol, ",", D, ",", T, ",", O, ",", H, ",", L, ",", C, ",", V, ",", OI);
                                if (SecName != "" && V != 0)
                                {
                                    Strwriter.WriteLine(a);
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        abc++;
                    }
                    Reader.ReadMaster();
                }

                Reader.CloseDirectory();
                Strwriter.Close();
                Strwriter.Dispose();
            }
            catch
            {
                Reader.CloseDirectory();
                Strwriter.Close();
                Strwriter.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
```

Please help me

Thanks in advance

```
    }
```

Comment: Jesus! Start fixing your question.

Comment: Have you tried implementing recursion? :)

Comment: implementing recursion means?

Answer (score 2):

you can use System.IO class library DirectoryInfo and FileInfo class and the logic goes as follows

1) Create two functions on to process directory and one to process file
2) In which directory read function reads validate if the item is file or directory 
3) If the item is directory it recursively calls itself
4) If the item is file it send it to file process method for processing

```
 public void fnProcessDirectory(string strPath)
    {
        if (File.Exists(strPath))
        {
            fnProcessFile(strPath);
        }
        else if (Directory.Exists(strPath))
        {
            string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(strPath);
            string[] subdirEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(strPath);

            foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
            {
                fnProcessFile(fileName);
            }

            foreach (string dirName in subdirEntries)
            {
                fnProcessDirectory(dirName);
            }
        }
    }

    public void fnProcessFile(string strPath)
    {
        //ProcessFile
    }
```

Comment: an error occurs it high lights this line  Reader.OpenDirectory(txtSourceBOBOMCX.Text); and the error is the directory does not contain any betastock files

Comment: can u add this code to my code i am new to C# can u please add it may be i am doing mistake that is why i am getting the error please can u add for me

Comment: there is not need to use open directory you can use getdirectories and getfiles to the contents of a folder and then iterate using foreach to process.

Comment: how to use multiple path in a code for example: string path = "C:\\work"; string path2 = "C:\\Business";

Comment: how to use multiple path in a code . there are many subfiles in a folder. i want to download the subfiles contain in it by multiple or triple string for example : - work is the main folder and Business,job are the subfiles i want to download all the subfiles by using string path = "C:\\Work\Business"; string path2 = "C:\\Work\job"; how can i download files by multiple string